# Get Field Label in a Formula Field

Tags: formula

Is it possible to get the Field Label in a Formula Field?

I want to create a formula field that validates if some fields are filled. So, I want to avoid creating a Custom label for each field. Is there a way to get the field Label in a formula field?

```
IF( isBlank(Account.BillingStreet), 'Billing Address' & BR(), '') &
IF( isBlank(Account.BillingCity) , 'Billing City' & BR(), '')
```

I would like some as we have in visualforce...

```
!$ObjectType.ABC__c.Fields.CreatedBy.Label
```

Comment: Where are you tried to use this formula field? on a record page?

Comment: I am trying to use in a formula field